# Scroll down automatically JTextArea for show the last lines added

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scrollbar, jtextarea

I have written a Java application that receives information from a server every 10 seconds. I am wanting to display this information on a form.

Currently I am using a JTextArea. However, once the JTextArea is filled up, I cannot see the new information that is added to this JTextArea. Do I need to add scroll bars to the JTextArea? Or is there a completely new different control for GUI forms that is recommended to display information that is added every x seconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DefaultCaret` tries to make itself visible which may lead to scrolling of a text component within `JScrollPane`. The default caret behavior can be changed by the `DefaultCaret#setUpdatePolicy` method.

Assumption that the name of your variable is `textArea`, you only need to modify the policy of caret:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret(); // ←
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);       // ←
...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
```

<sub>* Thanks, mKorbel</sub>

Comment: please to use `DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();` and `caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);` instead,

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to add scroll bars to the JTextArea?

Add the text area to a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more information & examples.

Here is an example:

[image: Text Area - Scrollable]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextAreaScrolling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JTextArea out = 
                        new JTextArea(5,10); // suggest columns & rows
                JScrollPane outScroll = new JScrollPane(out);

                File f = new File("TextAreaScrolling.java");
                try {
                    Reader reader = new FileReader(f);
                    out.read(reader, f);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outScroll);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel  Sure, but make it a 'systematic down vote' that will get recognized as such, like the group of 4 down votes that this was amongst.  ;)

Comment: +1 because my result is very diferrent (EDIT low battery in my wireless keyboard)